# Start empty Excel workbook without any worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

Creating a new Excel workbook as in:

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Set xl = New Excel.Application
xl.Visible = False
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
```

Is there an easy way to stop Excel automatically creating Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3?

I can always delete these unwanted sheets afterwards but that feels like a clunky solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
xl.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
```

More Information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221688%28v=office.11%29.aspx) (Scroll down to `Add method as it applies to the Workbooks object.`)

Full Code:

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim restoreSheetsInNewWorkbook As Long

Set xl =  New Excel.Application
restoreSheetsInNewWorkbook = xl.SheetsInNewWorkbook
xl.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1

Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
xl.SheetsInNewWorkbook = restoreSheetsInNewWorkbook 'or just set it to 3'
```

Comment: Don't forget that this needs to be restored to its original setting if you do not wish to annoy users.

Comment: so there is no way to start off with no sheets?

Comment: @hawbsl, a workbook must have at least one sheet. Don't add any workbooks if you want an _empty_ excel/app. object.

Comment: If you want to start with a specific kind of sheet you can use one of the ENUM Values that are specified in the MSDN link above as the Template. e.g. `Workbooks.Add xlWBATChart`

Comment: Accepted @marg's answer but really it was @NickD's comment which gave me my answer. @NickD if you want to post your comment as an answer i'll accept that instead.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The only issue remaining is that the new sheets are added on the left, instead of on the right. Anyone knows how to fix this???

Answer (score 4):

Can't create one without any sheets (to the best of my knowledge), but you can create a workbook with a single sheet *without messing around with the user's settings.*

```
dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can:

Excel 2003
Tools>Options>General Tab and change the "Sheets in new workbook" to 1

Excel 2007
Office Button>Excel Options>Popular Section>When creating new workbooks...>Include this many sheets>1

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub DeleteSheets()
Dim DeleteSheet As Variant
Dim ws              As Worksheet
DeleteSheet = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each ws In Worksheets

   If IsInArray(ws.Name, DeleteSheet) Then ws.Delete

Next

End Sub


Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim Ret As Boolean
Ret = False
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If VBA.UCase(stringToBeFound) = VBA.UCase(arr(i)) Then
       Ret = True
       Exit For
    End If
Next i
IsInArray = Ret
End Function
```

Comment: Add explanation to your answer